# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract - should we use our table column names?

Tags: zend-framework

Zend_Db_Table_Abstract insert method will accept an array of $data containing column value pairs.

**Should that column names inside the array, correspond, exactly, to our database table column names ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

On the array passed we NEED to make sure our keys name on that array correspond, exactly, to our table column names.